# Framework for kernel developer's first stab at web dev?

Tags: frameworks, web

Like the title says, I am currently employed writing a UNIX kernel and usermode apps in C. I've picked up a small web development side project, and I'm trying to figure out where to begin. The internet should be great for researching something like this, but there are so many options and so many people with strong opinions.

Project requirements:

- Frontend and admin login, user accounts
- Sessions, cookies
- Database (that can scale)
- HTTPS, secure CC info
- Post dynamic content like news, etc.

I'm familiar with:

- Linux/Unix, Windows (would prefer Linux for something like this probably)
- Apache (I used a little bit of PHP once)
- C, C++, C#, Python (I love Python), SQL, a few others

I'm wondering: what are some strong web frameworks at the moment? Which will be easy to pick up for a hobby project, but can scale if necessary? Would I be better off learning PHP because it's not abstracted too far from HTTP, or should I plug in to Django or something and let it do the work for me? Which are the most prevalent frameworks for single-developer projects, and why?

Thanks much.

Comment: You are employed to write, alone, a whole Unix kernel?!?! Given the variety of hardware, a whole life might not be enough!!

Comment: No... my day job is on a large team working on a kernel. The question is about a web development side project that I'm working on in my spare time.